# Cardinality of collection of subfields of $\mathbb C$

Tags: field-theory, cardinals

The question is just curiosity on my part. The title says it all. I can see that the cardinality is at least $\aleph_1$ (take simple extensions by an uncountable family of transcendental numbers). But is the cardinality the same as that of all subsets of $\mathbb C$? As a proof strategy, I'd wonder about finding an uncountable set such that any subset is "mutually transcendental", but this sounds like a lot to ask.

Comment: See  my Q  # 1468996   Cardinal of the set of subfields of the Reals... which has a nice short answer

Comment: Thanks - I'm surprised google didn't pull up your question. I did look first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, the set $\{ \mbox{subfields of } \Bbb{C} \}$ has cardinality almost  $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.

If you fix a transcendence basis $B$ of the extension $\Bbb{C} / \Bbb{Q}$, necessarily $|B| = \mathfrak{c}$.

Now, $$\{ \Bbb{Q}(S): S \in \mathcal{P}(B)\}$$
is a set of distinct subfields of $\Bbb{C}$ whose cardinality is exactly $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$. It follows that the cardinality of the set $\{ \mbox{subfields of } \Bbb{C} \}$ is exactly $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this is obvious if you know about transcendence bases.

Comment: This is false, unless you assume GCH - what you can really show is that the set of subfields has cardinality $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. But this is **not the same thing** as $\aleph_2$, in general!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sorry, I didn't know that! Is it correct now?

Comment: @Crostul Yup, that's right! The issue is that it's quite possible for there to be sets intermediate in size between the countable and the continuum. Such sets would have to be very weird, in precise senses, but they could exist. (Similarly for "between continuum and powerset of continuum," etc.)